# Maven distributionManagement for multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, github

So I recently changed a project of mine to have multiple modules and a root module instead of just one module. Before the change I had this in my pom

```
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub Freakyville Apache Maven Packages</name>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/Freakyville/Utils</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

But after I split it up into multiple modules it doesn't work anymore. This is my root module pom file now

```
<modules>
    <module>UtilsMain</module>
    <module>UtilsInterfaces</module>
    <module>UtilsV1_8</module>
    <module>UtilsV1_13</module>
</modules>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub Freakyville Apache Maven Packages</name>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/Freakyville/Utils</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

However when trying to run mvn deploy with this configuration it just tries to upload the pom file which isn't what I want. I would want the jar file generated by the module `UtilsMain`. I tried putting the `<distributionManagement>` inside the  `UtilsMain` module without any luck

Is there anyway for me to specify which module it should upload from?

Edit:

After the comment from @JF Meier I wanted to include the error when trying to deploy

`transfer failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/Freakyville/Utils/io/github/freakyville/Utils/1.16.26/Utils-1.16.26.pom 422 Unprocessable Entity`

I suppose this is my project isnt setup to accept deployed pom files? Do I have to do that? And in that case how?

Comment: Usually, calling `deploy` builds and uploads all modules.

Comment: Ah alright thx @JFMeier however the error i am getting is `transfer failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/Freakyville/Utils/io/github/freakyville/Utils/1.16.26/Utils-1.16.26.pom 422 Unprocessable Entity` - I suppose that is because github packages doesnt accept the pom file? Is there any way for me to allow it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change your groupid to a new unused one

Comment: How should this be related to the groupId?

Comment: This worked! So I got it working as seen here https://gyazo.com/30c2b193c00efe7ebff134e3ab60772b - my guess would be that github only allows one type of file in each package? - So when I try to upload the pom file to the previous path of the Jar file it doenst work